# Syntax error on LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

What is wrong here?

```
SELECT u.id
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN group g ON g.id=u.group_id
```

The following error is returned

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
use near 'group g ON g.id=u.group_id LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP` is a reserved word in the SQL standard due to the `GROUP BY` clause. Even Stack Overflow highlights it with blue ;)

If you want to use `group` as an identifier, you must quote it like this:

```
`group`
```

You may also rename the table to something more meaningful, like `UserGroup`. That will solve your issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

"group" is a reserved keyword of MySQL.

You can avoid this error with the next query:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN `group` g ON g.id=u.group_id
```

It's recommended to avoid using "group" as a table name.

Answer (score 1):

'group' is a keyword of SQL. You can try this:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM 'user' u
LEFT JOIN 'group' g ON u.group_id = g.id
```